# Установка Composer на хостинг

Tags: linux, php, composer, хостинг

Здравствуйте.

Хотелось бы установить фреймворк на хост через composer. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю куда нужно вводить команды наподобие "php composer.phar install". Хостинг на Linux.

Comment: если есть рут доступ, то через SSH клиент putty http://putty.org.ru/download.html

Answer (score 2):

Подключаешься к хостеру по SSH, например, с помощью [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html), в нем уже вводишь команды как на локальной машине.

Только условие. Хостер должен поддерживать такое подключение, и разрешены будут не все команды. Поддерживается ли доступ по SSH и что через него можно делать, можно узнать у хостера.